# Table in bootstrap crashes when creating dynamic content

Tags: php, css, bootstrap-4, html-table, datatable

I am creating a table with bootstrap and I am adding content to it through data saved in a database.
The problem is that the table is divided into 4.
[image]

First THE IMAGE, secondly the NAME OF THE PRODUCT (coffee), thirdly THE DETAIL (small coffee) and fourthly the PRICE.
So far so good, BUT when the product has NO image, it breaks. and it looks like this:

[image]

What I do is that IF the condition of NOT having an image is met then it DOES NOT create the `<td> </td>` and clearly here it breaks, but I cannot find a solution, here the code:

```
  <?php if(!empty($filaCategoria['descripcion'])){
   $rowDescripcion=2;   
   $detalleTableTop="detalleTableTop";
  }else{
   $rowDescripcion=1;   
   $detalleTableTop="";
  }
  ?>
<?php if(!empty($filaCategoria['imagenproducto'])){?>

  <td rowspan="<?php echo $rowDescripcion ; ?>" colspan="1" width="75px">

  <img src="<?php echo $filaCategoria['imagenproducto'];?>" width="75px">

  </td>
  <?php }; ?>

  <td class="col-12 <?php echo $detalleTableTop ;?>" >
  <?php echo $filaCategoria['producto'];?>

  </td>
  <td rowspan="<?php echo $rowDescripcion ; ?>" colspan="1">$<?php echo $filaCategoria['precio'];?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php if(!empty($filaCategoria['descripcion'])){?>

  <tr>
    <td class="toptable detalleTable">
    <span class="detalle"><?php echo $filaCategoria['descripcion'] ;?></strong></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You could instead insert an "empty" image instead of changing anything else.

Comment: Yes, it is a solution, but what I want is to avoid that margin, where the image was, and leave more space for the text

Comment: On that note, look into table's `colspan`. When there is no image, set `colspan` to `2` to fill the other data where an image would otherwise begin with so the columns are joined into one.